# callback gets called before rest of the function executed

Tags: javascript, callback

I recreated this example (from link given below) to understand callbacks. The problem is that the callback gets executed before the parent function 'first()' finishes. setTimeout works fine but callback doesn't wait until after the above . If i comment out line 1 and 3 of first() i.e. the timeout part, then it logs in the right order.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function second() {
    console.log("second/callback function")
}

function first(callback){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("first function")
    }, 1000 );
    callback();
}

first(second);
```

If this is working fine and i misunderstand the nature of setTimeout, then please give another example where the callback can be seen waiting.
Link:
https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-a-callback-aba4da2deced
Note: I know very little JS, was actually working in PHP, so kindly give a simple explanation. Thanks

Comment: You called `callback` synchronously, right before `first` ends... did you want to put it *inside* the `setTimeout`?

Comment: no, i wanted it called after statement console.log("first function"); which is delayed a certain amount of time.

Comment: In that case you would have to put callback() inside setTimeout, only then it will wait for 1 sec, and then print "first function" and then run callback()

Comment: thanks. i get it. but setTimeout was just to simulate. how can i change this code so that callback gets called after printing "first function" or anything else above it, no matter how long it takes, not just a fixed time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you misunderstand how `setTimeout()` works. This tool called Loupe by Philip Roberts may help you understand. I've taken your code placed it into the tool which will allow you to visualise what is actually happening - [link to Loupe](http://latentflip.com/loupe/?code=ZnVuY3Rpb24gc2Vjb25kKCkgewogICAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coInNlY29uZC9jYWxsYmFjayBmdW5jdGlvbiIpCn0KCmZ1bmN0aW9uIGZpcnN0KGNhbGxiYWNrKXsKICAgIHNldFRpbWVvdXQoZnVuY3Rpb24oKXsKICAgICAgICBjb25zb2xlLmxvZygiZmlyc3QgZnVuY3Rpb24iKQogICAgfSwgMTAwMCApOwogICAgY2FsbGJhY2soKTsKfQoKZmlyc3Qoc2Vjb25kKTs%3D!!!PGJ1dHRvbj5DbGljayBtZSE8L2J1dHRvbj4%3D)

When you use `setTimeout`, that function provided as the first parameter is delayed for the number of milliseconds provided in the second parameter (in your example, this is `1000`). The rest of your code will continue to execute in order until this timeout has lapsed.

If you want your `callback` function to execute after the given timeout: you can actually just write it such like:

`setTimeout(callback, 1000)` <- Since `callback` is already a function, you don't need to wrap it in another function  unless you wish to do other operations before calling the callback.

---

**Update 1 (2018-10-26):**

```js
function second() {
    console.log("second/callback function")
}

function first(callback){
    console.log("first function")
    setTimeout(callback, 1000);
}

first(second);
```

Comment: Another fantastic article which really helped me learn how JavaScript tasks, queues and schedules are executed is this article by Jake Archibald: https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/

Comment: @justrysism thanks. i understand the flow of execution but i want the callback to wait as long as the code above it doesn't execute in this case, to wait until "first function" is logged. i used setTimeout just to simulate a real environment where callback should have to wait for ,say a server response. can you give a better example since it appear setTimeout wasn't the proper choice.

Comment: @Awaisome see **Update 1** for an example based on your example.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are calling "callback" synchronously which means first function will wait for second(callback) function to be completed and then proceed with it's execution. To understand it better I have put console log at other places as well. Pls try below and see if you now have better understanding for the same

```js
function second() {
 console.log('second method started')
        setTimeout(() => console.log("second function executed"), 1000)
 console.log('second method finished')
}

function first(callback){
 console.log('first method started')
        setTimeout(() => console.log("first function executed"), 1000 );
        callback();
 console.log('first method finished')
}

first(second);
```