# What is the proper way to define a callback that is going to run after the function calling it?

Tags: javascript, callback

For instance, I would like to define a callback that shows a message when a task was finished **only using callbacks**. Please, don't talk about Promises, I know it can be applied here.

**1. My first try:**

```
function doHomeWork (subject, callback) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`Started my ${subject} homework`);
    }, 500);
    callback(subject);
}

function finishedHomework (subject) {
    console.log(`Finished my ${subject} homework`);
}

doHomeWork('math', finishedHomework);
```

This prints `Finished..` before `Started..` because `callback(subject)` doesn't wait for the end of `setTimeout`.

If I call `callback(subject)` into the `setTimeout` it is gonna print both messages at the same time, not what I want.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52941184/7948731) puts the `setTimeout` in the callback call, but, in my hypothetical case, what consumes time is `doHomeWork`, not the callback that is `finishedHomeWork`, so, it is not valid for this example.

**2. My second try:**

```
function homeWork (subject, callback) {
    doHomeWork(subject);
    callback(subject);
}

function doHomeWork (subject) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`Started my ${subject} homework`);
    }, 500);
}

function finishedHomework (subject) {
    console.log(`Finished my ${subject} homework`);
}

homeWork('math', finishedHomework);
```

This also prints `Finished..` before `Started..`, because `callback(subject)` doesn't wait for `doHomeWork(subject)`.

So, the callback explanation says it is a function that is going to run after the function calling it, isn't it? But, as my examples showed, I didn't find the way to define it to run after the finish of `doHomeWork`.

What is missing?

Comment: You're not actually calling the callback *inside* the setTimeout, just after it's scheduled. Just naming it callback isn't magically going to call it at the right time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this is why you need promises.

Javascript doesn't care that your second parameter is a callback. It'll run the callback function as soon as it can because it doesn't wait for the preceding call to finish, which is the behavior you've demonstrated in your two examples.

To do this with callbacks only, put your callback inside the `setTimeout` function.

```
function doHomeWork (subject, callback) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`Started my ${subject} homework`);
        callback(subject); // <---------   CHANGE MADE HERE
    }, 500);
    //callback(subject)  // Remove this line, and move it up ^^^
}

function finishedHomework (subject) {
    console.log(`Finished my ${subject} homework`);
}

doHomeWork('math', finishedHomework);
```

**However**, you should just use Promises. They are actually easy and much more readable. The same function could be written as:

```
function doHomeWork (subject) {
  return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {   //Turns a regular funciton into a promise
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`Started my ${subject} homework`);
        resolve(subject);
    }, 500);
  }); 
}

function finishedHomework (subject) {
    console.log(`Finished my ${subject} homework`);
}

doHomeWork('math').then( (subject) => { //since doHomeWork returns a promise we can use .then() on it
    finishedHomework(subject);
});
```

Comment: I saw somewhere that callback will run at the end of the calling function. Turns out it is a wrong way to explain callbacks. What you just wrote is the thing I was expecting to see: Javascript doesn't care..

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of libraries that have created the functions which accept callbacks for you, typically they can accept a callback but what you don't see is that they make sure the callback only runs after the initial function is complete and it's not as simple as just invoking it inside the parent function.

Comment: But I'd say never assume javascript will wait for a function to finish. If something is going to take a non-insignificant amount of time such as HTTP requests, large data processing, or anything that deals with time (setTimeout) then you should look to turn the function into a promise so you can rest assured things will run in the correct order.

Answer (score 2):

Hi the problem is that when is that the function

```
() => {console.log(`Started my ${subject} homework`);}
```

runs only when the setTimeout end so the best soluction that i see is

```
function doHomeWork (subject, callback) {
    console.log(`Started my ${subject} homework`);
    setTimeout(() => {
        callback(subject);
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: I wrote about that in the question, it is like the finishedHomework is consuming time, but, I'm mimicking that doHomeWork takes some time to run.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try wrapping your callback in an anonymous function? (Not tested, but it is usually my first guess whenever I have the same problem you are dealing with.)

```
homeWork('math', function(){finishedHomework()});
```

Comment: Why would you do that, instead of just *passing the function*? What difference would it make?